# Why does Pa_GetStreamTime() return an error?

Tags: c++, portaudio

When I call `Pa_GetStreamTime()` like this (after opening and starting the stream), it returns 0.0 as a result, meaning it experienced an error.

```
Pa_StartStream(stream);
double streamTime = Pa_GetStreamTime(stream);
```

How can I fix it so that I can get the current time using `Pa_GetStreamTime()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pa_GetStreamTime()` will only work after the callback function is called for the first time. Try delaying before getting the stream time.

```
Pa_StartStream(stream);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
double streamTime = Pa_GetStreamTime(stream);
```